# Extension to add Angular Material support to Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, angular-material

Is there an extension to add Angular Material support, like intellisense, to Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a little bit of material intellisense support with ReSharper and its Angular for ReSharper extension. There is no another way as far as I know.